# Paging To The End Of A Data View Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, dataviewwebpart

Hopefully you can help me with this.

I've displayed an Announcement web part on a page with 20 items. I opened up SharePoint Designer 2007 and set the paging to 6 items. I've added a little bit of (OOB) functionality so that I have buttons for START, PREVIOUS, and NEXT. These work well without any problems but I'm wondering how do I get END to work? I tried using the $LastRow & $RealLastRow values supplied by the web part but those just give me the number of how many items are in the current view, not the total items in the list.

Little help!

Comment: One of the things I really, really wish Microsoft would provide for the OOTB xsl templates for the Data View Web Part!